# converter código javascript para jquery

Tags: jquery

Como ficaria esse código em javascript:

```
 var ctx1 = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut1").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx1).Doughnut(data1, options);
    legend(document.getElementById("lineLegend1"), data1);
```

Em jQuery?

Comment: Por quê o interesse em fazer em jQuery? Me parece sucinto esse código.

Comment: Já uso o jQuery no meu projeto, e o código fica bem mais simples e menor.

Comment: Se o código em questão é esse deixa como está. O jQuery está a ser cada vez menos usado. jQuery é feito com JavaScript, por isso quanto menos jQuery melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há muito o que fazer no seu código, apenas pegar os elementos pelo `#id` via jQuery.

```
var ctx1 = $("#GraficoDonut1")[0].getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx1).Doughnut(data1, options);
legend($("#lineLegend1")[0], data1);
```

Comment: Mas como foi dito, não há necessidade de usar jQuery aí, a performance do JavaScript puro é muito maior.